# Carregamento de bibliotecas em tempo de execução

Tags: java, jar, reflexão

Existe alguma contra-indicação em carregar bibliotecas `.jar` em tempo de execução?

Encontrei este código que faz isso:

```
URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;

try {
      Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
      method.setAccessible(true);
      method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[]{URL_CARREGAR});
} catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
      throw new IOException("Error, could not add URL to system classloader");
}
```

Este código funciona. Mas essa é a melhor maneira?

Quero carregar em tempo de execução para que novos JARs possam ser colocados em uma pasta e assim carregar novas funcionalidades a meu sistema. Como se fossem módulos adicionais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é contra-indicado carregar jars em tempo de execução, pelo contrário.
Desenvolver aplicações que funcionem dessa forma é o desejável. Porque assim podemos alterar uma parte do software sem precisar recompilá-lo por completo e sem sequer parar a execução do mesmo.

Seu pensamento está correto.

O uso deste tipo de abordagem pode ser observado nos plugins. Os plugins adicionam features a um software em tempo de execução. As vezes é preciso reiniciar o software para que ele possa carregar o plugin, mas nem por isso a beleza da solução é perdida.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.. Era bem o que eu imaginava e exatamente a resposta que eu precisava. Você sabe me dizer se poderia dar algum problema se eu carregar o mesmo jar duas vezes? Estou tratando para isso não acontecer, mais fiquei com esta duvida

Comment: Não tem problema. A JVM vai olhar as URLs na ordem em que elas aparecem no classpath. Ou seja, ela vai usar a primeira URL que for encontrada no classpath. Esse link explica como as classes são encontradas: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html Veja a parte: How the Java Launcher Finds JAR-class-path Classes

Answer (score 3):

Este código é bom, pois é versátil, simples, útil e flexível. Dá para deixá-lo um pouquinho melhor assim:

```java
public static void adicionarAoClasspath(String caminho) throws IOException {
   adicionarAoClasspath(new File(caminho).toURI().toURL());
}

public static void adicionarAoClasspath(URL url) throws IOException {
    URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    try {
        Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(sysloader, url);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException("Error, could not add URL to system classloader", t);
    }
}
```

A diferença está no encadeamento de exceções, no uso de varargs onde possível e no uso do literal de classe sem precisar de uma variável intermediária para isso. Além disso, ele parametriza o que no seu código original era o `URL_CARREGAR`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... E você esta certo código desse jeito é bem melhor... hoje o meu já esta bem parecido com este, pois carrega de uma lista de arquivos..